# How to assign point feature values to line features?

Tags: r, geometry, spatial-join, points-to-line, st

I have two datasets, one being a point feature dataset and the other being a line feature dataset. Each point feature contains a traffic count value that I want to assign to the corresponding line feature, representing the road, via a spatial join. The preferred result would be that two of the three values from the point features will be assigned to the corresponding line (i.e. road); one of the point values should not be joined as it does not spatially intersect with a line (see the `tmap` part of the code). However, with my current code I am not succeeding in the spatial join:

```
#necessary libraries
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(osmdata)
library(dplyr)
library(rgdal)
library(utils)
library(rgeos)
library(gstat)

## == import road shapefile via OpenStreetMap == ##

#intialize coordinates ()
coor_1 = 6.4949
coor_3 = 6.6216
coor_2 = 51.6161
coor_4 = 51.5074

#select type
f <- opq(bbox = c(coor_1, coor_2, coor_3, coor_4)) %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = 'highway', value = 'primary')

roads = osmdata_sf(f)
plot(roads$osm_lines[0])

#assign to variable
roads <- roads$osm_lines

#aggregate roads by road number
aggregate_roads <- roads %>% 
  group_by(ref) %>% 
  summarise()

plot(aggregate_roads)

## == create point features dataset == ##

#initialize coordinates
points_long <- c(6.564702, 6.534903, 6.534677)
points_lat <- c(51.54378, 51.59492, 51.59278)
traffic <- c(2000, 1000, 1500)
#merge columns to one dataset
points_df <- data.frame(points_long, points_lat, traffic)

coords <- points_df[ , c("points_long", "points_lat")]   # coordinates
crs    <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") # crs

# make the SpatialPointsDataFrame object
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords      = coords,
                               data        = points_df, 
                               proj4string = crs)

## == assign point values to lines (roads) == ##
st_line <- st_as_sf(aggregate_roads)
st_poi <- st_as_sf(spdf)

#visualize locations of point- and line features via tmap
tmap_mode("view")

tm_shape(st_line) +
  tm_lines(col ='red') +
  tm_shape(st_poi) +
  tm_dots()

## current spatial join options do not work!

#filter lines that intersect with points - option A
line_vals <- st_line[st_poi, ]
view(line_vals)
#spatial join - option B
join_lines_points <- st_join(st_line, st_poi, join = st_intersects, left=T) # join points
view(join_lines_points)
```

Both options that I tried in my code show an empty output.

How can I successfully join the traffic values of the points to the corresponding line, based on the location?

Comment: Point-on-line is a particularly fraught operation -- some coordinate values can't be stored by IEEE floating-point representation.  The operation to perform is point-within-a-distance-of-a-line.